# React Flask Postgres does not respond on localhost 3000 when starting in docker container with docker-compose

Tags: reactjs, docker, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to dockerize my react-flask-postgres application and when I start it in the console with npm start in the react directory and python server.py then it works. So I started to write a dockerfile for my python backend:

```
# This Dockerfile builds the React client and API together

# Build step #1: build the React front end
FROM node:latest as build-step
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY ./client/package.json ./client/package-lock.json ./
COPY ./client/src ./src
COPY ./client/public ./public
RUN npm update
RUN npm run build

# Build step #2: build the API with the client as static files
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-step /app/build ./build
RUN mkdir ./api
COPY ./backend/ ./api/
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./unikarlendercerts/ ./unikarlendercerts/
WORKDIR /app/api
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ENV FLASK_ENV production
ENV FLASK_DEBUG 0

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["gunicorn", "-c", "python:config.gunicorn", "server:app"]
```

and then I wrote this docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASS}
    volumes:
      - .postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/new/data
    container_name: flask_postgres

  react-flask-app:
    build: .
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASS}
      WEB_BIND: ${WEB_BIND}
      PRIVKEY: ${PRIVKEY}
      CERT: ${CERT}
      CHAIN: ${CHAIN}
    links:
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    container_name: react-flask-app
    image: react-flask-app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

What Have I done wrong?
When I want to access it it says:
[image]

but i have this output in my docker containers when they run
so i guess they work fine?
[image]

[image]

I tried to change all ports and that did not work. I treid changing in the package.json. then i tried to reinstall with npm install  and npm build.